# Passing "direct" struct as function in C

Tags: c, function, structure

I have a simple question about structures in C.

I have this struct and this function:

```
struct Vec2
{
  int x;
  int y;
}

void draw(Sprite* sprite, struct Vec2 pos);
```

Is there anyway to do the equivalent in c++?

```
draw(foo, new Vec2(10, 20));
```

I tried this but the compiler doesn't agree with me:

```
draw(foo, {10, 20} );
```

Anybody to help ?

Edit: I use Visual C++ 2008 Express in C++ mode, but for my school I must code in straight C, not C++

Comment: Your problem isn't wholly clear but get rid of the `new` in the C++ version and see what happens.

Comment: In C++, `new` gives you a pointer to a `Vec2`; your `draw` function expects a value of type `Vec2`, not a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your compiler supports C99 or later, you can use a *compound literal*:

```
draw(foo, (struct Vec2){10, 20});
```

or, if you want to be more explicit about the member names:

```
draw(foo, (struct Vec2){.x = 10, .y = 20});
```

(Note that Microsoft's C compiler doesn't support C99, which could limit the portability of your code.)

Comment: Exactly, for my school i must work with visual c++ express 2008, which doesn't let me do this.. Thank you anyway

Comment: Note that this feature is called *compound literals* (C99 §6.5.2); the second example above also includes *designated initializers* (C99 §6.7.8).

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is :

```
struct Vec2 make_Vec2( int x, int y ) {
  struct Vec2 vec;
  vec.x = x; vec.y = y;
  return vec;
}

...
draw( foo, make_Vec2( 10, 20 ) );
```

Comment: Or, slightly shorter: struct Vec2 vec = { x, y }; return vec;

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a working example with @Keith Thompson's answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct two{
 int x;
 int y;
};
draw(struct two t){
    printf("\nx=%d y=%d\n", t.x, t.y);
}
int main(){
 draw((struct two){1,2});
 draw((struct two){.y = 1, .x = 2});
}
```

Output:

```
:~$ ./a.out 

 x=1 y=2

 x=2 y=1
```